# Is there an easy way to run,use & display desktop programs on web browser from my own computer without uploading on other server or using online app?

Tags: windows, web, browser, server, xampp

For example there is a calculator app inside my computer so can i run ,use and display calculator app on web browser from my computer but only by using server like xammp or other offline software without uploading on others server or using online app ? please provide easy solution.

Comment: There is no general solution to visualize desktop programs (so rich client applications) in a web browser. There are some projects working on this, but the platforms they are based on are not commonly used on MS-Windows systems (for example the great Qt tool kit).

Answer (score 0):

You can try OnlineVNC? http://www.onlinevnc.com/
I'm not sure if it fits your criteria though. It's a server part that you install on your PC so that you can remote it from a browser.